# Centos: Port forwarding doesn't work any more

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

All, since I've restarted my server after installing the latest kernel (3.10.0-693.2.2), I'm not able to get my port forwarding working any more.

The current setup is as follows. My ISP at home doesn't give public IP addresses. In order to reach my servers at home (running on Proxmox), I do forward all requests on my webserver in a datacenter on port 8006 via OpenVPN to Proxmox (ip 10.8.0.26) at home.

The rules that I've been using since more than a year on the server with public IP address:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 8006 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.26:8006
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.8.0.26 --dport 8006 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
```

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 ens3


ifconfig tun0
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 100  bytes 15105 (14.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 347  bytes 38520 (37.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Reboots in the past never caused problems, but now I'm not able to get it working any more. The webserver can connect to port 8006 to 10.8.0.26. Systems connected to the VPN can also connect without any problems. So, it seems to be the forwarding itself which is not working.
Trying to connect to the webserver port 8006 will result in a timeout.

Does someone have a clue what is going on here?

Thanks a lot,
Greg

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/questions/586486/how-to-do-the-port-forwarding-from-one-ip-to-another-ip-in-same-network

Comment: post the old and the new kernel config. iptables got depricated so make sure it's enabled. 4.9 would be the latest lts.

Comment: Hmm, you might have a point there: systemctl status iptables: Unit iptables.service could not be found. Current installed version: iptables-1.4.21-18.0.1.el7.centos.x86_64. Where can I find the config files and what is to be used instead of iptables; nftables?

Comment: @A.B Here's the output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/25752138/ This is by default after a reboot (I use docker containers). Then I run a script which contains the above rules. Even when I don't run the script, but just the above ones, it fails to forward.

Comment: Ok, I could solve it. The FORWARD rule has been deleted and replaced by iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.8.0.26 --dport 8006 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1. I don't know why it did work in the past and now not any more.